# 720KB toolip not displaying on ion tab

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, tooltip

in my project, i currently have a tabs controller template that allows the user to navigate to other views

I am currently using the 720KB tooltip in my ionic project. I have gotten it to work for all my elements except for the ion tabs in the tabs controller template.

With 720KB all you need to do is add this `tooltips tooltip-template="I'm a tooltip!"` to any element you will have the tooltip on hover for that specific element.

this is my code in the ionic tab controller

```
<ion-view id="page1" ng-app="720kb">
```

```
<ion-tab title="Introduction" icon-off="acc-intro-off" icon-on="acc-intro-on" href="#/page1/page3" id="tabsController-tab3">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab2"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Awards " icon-off="acc-category-off" icon-on="acc-category-on" href="#/page1/page4" id="tabsController-tab4">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab3"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Awards Vote" icon-off="acc-vote-off" icon-on="acc-vote-on" href="#/page1/page6" id="tabsController-tab5">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab6"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Award Nomination" icon-off="acc-nomination-off" icon-on="acc-nomination-on" href="#/page1/page5" id="tabsController-tab6">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab5"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Result Category" icon-off="acc-results-off" icon-on="acc-results-on" href="#/page1/page7" id="tabsController-tab7">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab7"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

I have a attempted to put a 720KB tool tip on the first ion tab but it does not appear on hover. If I inspect in chrome however, I see that the tool tip is generated.

Here is an example it working with any other element
[image]

However when I attach `tooltips tooltip-template="I'm a tooltip!"` to an ion-tab, it does not display however I see the html generated in the inspect as shown here[image]

Comment: i tried to triggered the tooltip with both on hover and focus using the inspect tool but no luck

Comment: @have you injected its dependency '720kb.tooltips' in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Trigger the tooltip on focus event.